# Determine weak limit points

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

A measure $\eta $ is called weak limit point from $\Gamma$, if a sequence $\Gamma \backslash \{\eta\}$ exists, that converges weakly to $\eta$ Let $\mu_n:= U_{\{\frac1n,\frac2n,\dots,\frac{n-1}{n},1\}}$. Determine all weak limit points (measure on ($\mathbb R,B$)) of the set $\{\mu_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N} $ for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

$U$ denotes the uniform distribution. Furthermore I think with $\Gamma $ is a subset of the set of all real valued probability measures meant.

I am absolutely cluessless here, some approaches and help are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mu$ be Lebesgue measure restricted to $[0,1]$, that is $\mu(E)=m(E\cap[0,1])$ (where $m$ is Lebesgue measure). If $f$ is continuous then $\int fd\mu_n$ is just a Riemann sum for $\int_0^1 f=\int f\,d\mu$. So $\mu_n\to\mu$ weakly; hence any subsequence also tends to $\mu$. So $\mu$ is the only weak limit point.

**Detail** added by request:

Say $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Since  $f$ is uniformlly continuous there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(t)-f(s)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|t-s|<\delta$.

If $n>1/\delta$ then $$\frac1n f(j/n)-\int_{(j-1)/n}^{j/n}f(t)\,dt=\int_{(j-1)/n}^{j/n}(f((j/n)-f(t))\,dt,$$
so $$\left|\frac1n f(j/n)-\int_{(j-1)/n}^{j/n}f(t)\,dt\right|\le\int_{(j-1)/n}^{j/n}|f((j/n)-f(t)|<\int_{(j-1)/n}^{j/n}\epsilon\,dt=\frac1n\epsilon.$$Hence$$\left|\int f\,d\mu_n-\int_0^1 f(t)\,dt\right|<\epsilon.$$

Comment: what do you mean with m? And could you add some more Details?

Comment: $m$ is Lebesgue measure. What else would you like me to explain? Sorry, but unless you say what part you don't get I can't imagine what other details there are to be added.

Comment: I do not understand the 2nd sentence

Comment: @J.D Detail added...